# how do I make changes to inpus from edit/update in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

I have he following code in my update action for a Controller.  The code works when in the create, but doesn't seem to kick in under update:

```
def update
 @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])

 # bug, why isn't this working? 
 unless @contact.fax.empty?
   @contact.fax = "1" + Phony.normalize(@contact.fax)
 end

 unless @contact.phone.empty?
   @contact.phone = "1" + Phony.normalize(@contact.phone)
end

if @contact.update_attributes(params[:contact])
   flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated contact."
   redirect_to @contact
 else
   render :action => 'edit'
 end
```

end

Answer (score 6, accepted):

these should be in your model. FAT model, SKINNY controller:

```
# contact.rb
...
# may need require 'phony' and include Phony
before_save :prep

def prep
  self.fax = 1+Phony.normalize(self.fax) unless self.fax.empty? || (self.fax.length == 11 && self.fax[0] == 1)
  self.phone = 1+Phony.normalize(self.phone) unless self.phone.empty? || (self.phone.length == 11 && self.phone[0] == 1)
end
...
```

**Edit:**

As I mentioned in my comment, it's better in terms of storage and efficiency and indexing to store as a bigint unsigned in your database and add the prettiness to the numbers in a method. This way, your site is always normalized (no two phone numbers will ever look different because they are formatted 'on the fly').

```
# sample methods
def phony
  str = self.phone.to_s
  "#{str[0..2]}-#{str[3..5]}-#{str[6..10]}"
end

# use a similar method for faxing, but I'll write
# this one differently just to show flexibility
def faxy
  str = self.fax.to_s
  "+1 (#{str[0..2]}) #{str[3..5]}-#{str[6..10]}"
end
```

Comment: @seth.vargo Not to get too far off-topic...heheh, would you know how to use shoulda to write a test for this?  I'm not sure....

Comment: @seth.vargo -- here's a problem -- it works the first time, adding the 1 and saving into the field.  But what happens when I open and edit that record.  It then tacks on a *second* "1" (need to make 1 a "1" string)...

Comment: @seth.vargo -- yep, it works the first time...but subsquent times, it keeps adding a "1"

Comment: @Angela - I don't use shoulda (missed your comment before), so sadly I don't. I recommending opening up another question.

Comment: very nice -- wow, 6 score on your answer, that is quite a good answer, and i thank you.

Comment: @Angela - Thanks! 10 and I get a badge :)

Comment: @seth -- your code blows up...typically I put in the phone numbers as 415-555-1212 for example, so that doesn't meet the condition, I think, anyway, I end up with alot of extra 1's...I think it needs to normalize the 415-555-1212 to 14155551212 which the first part does...I think not sure, still debugging now...

Comment: @Angela - You should not store the phone numbers as a string, but rather an unsigned bigint. Don't STORE it with the dashes. An unsigned bigint takes up far less memory and is indexed faster than strings (hence why PK and FK are usually numerical). Then you don't have to worry about how to store it in the database. Write the .phoney (or .faxy) method in your controller to return the formatted version. ill update

Comment: @Angela, I've added some more code that I think solves your problem in a more pragmatic way. Let's fix the problem, not treat the symtoms :)

Answer (score 1):

you never call `save` on `@contact` in your `unless` blocks, so your call to `@contact.update_attributes(params[:contact])` undoes any change you made in those blocks (because those keys in the `params` hash correspond to empty values).

```
def update
  @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])

  if @contact.update_attributes(params[:contact])
    @contact.update_attributes(:fax   => "1" + Phony.normalize(@contact.fax))   unless @contact.fax.empty?
    @contact.update_attributes(:phone => "1" + Phony.normalize(@contact.phone)) unless @contact.phone.empty?

    flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated contact."
    redirect_to @contact
  else
    render :action => 'edit'
  end
end
```

You could use `update_attribute` but that bypasses validation.

You could also use a `before_save` callback in the `Contact` class, but you would have to check if the `phone` or `fax` are already "normalized."

Comment: This should fix it, so I won't add an answer. Just note that you need to process the POST parameters in your UPDATE method before they'll exist in your model. It doesn't matter if you save it before or after update attributes, but until you update attributes the content that was input from the form isn't available via things like `@contact.fax` etc.

Comment: okay, I think I see...what if I put the normalization into the model will that do it even for the update?